# Сравнение дат flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

У меня есть дата, которая выбирается на клиенте через datepicker, а так же две даты приходят с сервера. Мне нужно сравнить эти даты - входит ли выбранная на клиенте дата в диапазон дат, пришедших с сервера. Я использую `isAfter` и `isBefore`, но они не включают крайних значений, т. е. если я выбираю дату 13.03, и с сервера пришла эта же дата, то условие не сработает. Как мне это побороть? Условие прикладываю, если это необходимо:

```
if (_instances[index].product == '$dropdownValue' &&
              _instances[index].isArchived == true &&
              selectedDate.isAfter(_instances[index].dateFrom) &&
              selectedDate.isBefore(_instances[index].dateTo))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать их наоборот с не:

```
!selectedDate.isBefore(_instances[index].dateFrom) &&
!selectedDate.isAfter(_instances[index].dateTo)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! И почему сам не додумался...)